# Why the ip address of VM change randomly on vm

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have 3 VM ,the ip address of evry vm change randomly.
I try to give each one a static ip by editing the /etc/network/interfaces file , this is the configuration of one of this 3 vms:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
#address 192.168.1.10
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#network 192.168.1.0
#broadcast 192.168.1.255


address 172.20.22.112
netmask 255.255.128.0
network 172.20.22.0
broadcast 172.20.22.231

#auto enp0s3
#iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

I just don't now the origin of this error and how to fix it.
Ps: sometimes I have the same ip for all vms and sometimes and sometimes the ip change during the usage of the vm.

Comment: What is the guest OS?

Comment: @Smock I have debian 10 on my pc and on the vms ubunutu server 18.04

Comment: not sure if [this helps](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu) but it looks like network config looks completely different in latest versions - do you have a /etc/netplan folder?

Comment: @Smock no I don't have